# Relationship Behind Triangulation and Congruent Polygons

Tags: geometry, planar-graphs, triangulation

I came across the definition below to see how $n$-sided polygons are defined to be congruent.

**Definition:** It is said that two $n-$gons are **congruent** iff their corresponding sides and corresponding angles are congruent.

> $\bullet$ It can be proven that any $n-$sided polygon can be partitioned into $n-2$ triangles by triangulation.
>
> $\bullet$ I personally would think the definition of congruent $n-$gons would be that two $n-$sided polygons are **congruent** iff each polygon can be partitioned into triangles in a way that leads two an isomorphism between their graphs as well as a correspondence of congruent triangles.
>
> > The reason I would think this is because the two polygons would be connected the same way by congruent triangles making the shapes themselves congruent.

$\textbf{Question:}$ Is there a relationship between these ideas? Is there any intuition behind how congruent polygons are defined? My concern is how this definition could imply two congruent shapes can be partitioned the same way by triangles.

Comment: Really the notion of [congruence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_(geometry)) that works for arbitrary shapes, not just polygons, is that two shapes are congruent if there exists a rigid transformation that maps one to the other. The given definition in terms of sides and angles is just an easy-to-check criterion that is equivalent to the underlying notion of rigid transformations. After all, one pair of equal-length sides fixes the rigid transformation, then equality of the angles and the remaining sides ensures that the remaining points agree with it.

Comment: Regarding your last question, you can apply the same rigid transformation to the triangulation as well.

Comment: How would you tell two polygons in this context are congruent then by an isometry? I know what an isometry is generally, but I am not sure how to relate these ideas by this concept.

Comment: If you're working only with classical Euclidean geometry, you can define two sets of points $\{P_1,P_2,\dots,P_n\}$ and $\{Q_1,Q_2,\dots,Q_n\}$ to be congruent if and only if all corresponding line segments $P_iP_j$ and $Q_iQ_j$ are congruent for all $i,j$. Thus we can build up the notion of isometry from the basic concept of congruence of line segments (i.e. equality of lengths). This definition should be easier to connect with both ideas of congruence in your question.